# Disabling a Django ModelForm Field without explicit declaration

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

I have this code:

```py
class MyModel(models.Model):
    input_field = model.CharField(max_length=100)


class MyModelForm(forms.ModelForm):

    input_field = forms.CharField(disabled=True)    

    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
```

I've also read from the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/forms/modelforms/#overriding-the-default-fields):

> When you explicitly instantiate a form field like this, it is important to understand how `ModelForm` and regular `Form` are related.
>
> ...
>
> Fields defined declaratively are left as-is, therefore any customizations made to Meta attributes such as widgets, labels, help_texts, or error_messages are ignored; these only apply to fields that are generated automatically.
>
> Similarly, fields defined declaratively do not draw their attributes like max_length or required from the corresponding model. If you want to maintain the behavior specified in the model, you must set the relevant arguments explicitly when declaring the form field.

Is it possible to pass kwargs to the Form Field in a way that lets me specify `disabled=True` without losing the benefits of the `ModelForm`s introspection and customisation? Essential, can I have my cake and eat it?

I'm aware that I can work around this by using `widgets = {'input_field': widgets.TextInput(attrs={'readonly':'readonly'})`} in the `Meta` class, but I'm interested if there's a better way available

It's also not clear whether modifying the `widgets` attribute as above will "inherit" the default configuration that the ModelForm would otherwise apply, such as inferring the `max_length` from the underlying model.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the easiest thing to do is to override `__init__`.

```
class MyModelForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = MyModel

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['input_field'].disabled = True
```